# How to Query from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database by the name CARS with 2 tables. I need help in querying data from both these tables and get a output based on ID(100)..

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://books.google.nl/books/about/Sams_Teach_Yourself_SQL_in_10_Minutes.html?id=RGE08zEHRwcC&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he following should answer your question. Ask for the fields you want(with a table identifier) in the SELECT clause and then JOIN the tables on the common ID:

```
    SELECT table1.ID, table1.GroupID, table1.Text, table2.GroupID, table2.Text 
    FROM table1 
    JOIN table2 
    ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

or:
Looking at is again I noticed table 1 and table 2 are identical in design, just hte entries are different. You can use UNION ALL to concatenate two SELECT statements

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2;
```

:)

To only return the entries with ID = 100

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 
    WHERE ID = 100 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM table2 
    WHERE ID = 100;
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your speedy comment. i dont have any understanding of programming so its basically a alien language to me.

Comment: however i tried it and it gave me a lot of ouput since i want a result only for 100.. how should i enter it

Comment: there is only 100 in the data you provided, but if you have to determine this in your code then you should add WHERE ID = 100

Comment: Excellent.. that worked just as i wanted... thanks a lot :)